# iOS14 old widget update to widget with edit ，old add widget edit button not work

Tags: ios, widget

iOS14 old widget update to widget with edit ，old add widget edit button not work. new add widget it can work, what should I do ,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a iOS14 bug.
You have to remove old widget and add a new widget, you can fix it.
Addition, you can reboot your phone, try it.